# How can I build a chatbot that replies to the same FAQ question which has different answers for different companies FAQ data in Rasa, Python

Tags: python, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I want to build a chatbot which answers questions based on FAQ data. I will be building the chatbot that answers question related to the FAQ data of different companies. Suppose there are 5 different companies, each having a separate set of FAQ's. Suppose, for two different companies, A and B the same FAQ question has different answers. Here is it possible to build one bot that can handle this scenario provided that the company name will be provided to the bot at the starting of the chat or do I need to build separate bots for answering questions on respective companies FAQ's? I will be using Python and Rasa for this task.

Comment: You could build one bot class that accepts a database object of faqs, then reacts to that. Then define one database per company

Comment: Database object of faqs as in ? By database per company, you mean one training_data.json  training file per company?

Comment: "respective companies FAQ's". Put them in a file or database you can store persistently. Build an API around getting ALL FAQs (not specific to a certain company). Then create as many searches, invoked by instances of different bots, as you need to filter the list when you ultimately display the data